# Question regarding to char* function member function in class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I am trying to learn c++ from Udacity. I need some clarification if what I am understanding is correct or not. So the code is the following.

TicTacToe Game:

```
class Board
{//the class tracks the game and the winner
    char positionsSelected[16];
    char winner;
    
public:
    //Constructor
    Board();
    int setPosition(int gridNumber, char user);
    char* getPositions(void);
};

char* getPositions(void)
    {//return all the positions on the board
        return positionsSelected;
    }
```

If you look at it, the member function `char* getPositions(void)` was declared inside of class.

I know assumption can be really bad, but this is what my thinking processes and questions were

1. Since you are basically reading a sequence of characters, that's why it has to be `char*`.
2. Why the parameter of `getPositions(void)` have to? Can that be the same as empty parenthesis ()?
3. If the functional prototype is `char* getPositions()`, does it mean that it returns the pointer? Can I make an assumption that return value from `char*getPosition(void)` is pointing to `char array(positionsSelected)`.
4. If my assumption is wrong on 3. Can I put something like this

```
char* getPositions(void){
    char* pointers;
    pointers = positionSelected;
    return pointers;
}
```

Any suggestions or explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated: Knowing the winner is not a responsibility with which I would task a Tic-Tac-Toe game board. To me a `board` should represent the board and be blissfully unaware of the game logic.

Comment: Note that by returning `positionsSelected` with no guards on it the caller of `getPositions` can do anything they want. Rather than opening up the whole game board to public scrutiny, you're better off having a function like `char get_position(int x, int y)` and only allow users to see a single character at a time. That way the true nature of the game board remains [encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). You can totally rewrite the guts of board and no one will ever know that it now stores the board in a cloud of magical fairy dust or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Since you are basically reading a sequence of characters, that's why it has to be char*.

Better would be to make the member `std::string positionsSelected;`.  Then you can just return `std::string const &` from your method.  This is both safer and simpler to use.

> 2. Why the parameter of getPositions(void) have to? Can that be the same as empty parenthesis ()?

Both syntaxes are accepted due to baggage from C, where they can mean different things:

- `void foo(void);` explicitly specifies that no arguments are accepted.
- `void foo();` does not specify what arguments are accepted.

In C++ they both mean the same thing: no arguments are accepted.  Empty parens are the preferred syntax (`char * getPositions();`).

> 3. If the functional prototype is char* getPositions(), does it mean that it returns the pointer? Can I make an assumption that return value from char*getPosition(void) is pointing to char array(positionsSelected).

Yes, you can make this assumption.  Arrays implicitly decay to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: "*Better would be to make the member `std::string positionsSelected;`. Then you can just return `std::string const &` from your method. This is both safer and simpler to use.*" - alternatively, `std::array<char, 16>` instead of `std::string`, then you don't have the overhead of dynamic memory allocation.